# Customize DisplayFor output

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-5.2, displayfor

I am making steady progress :)
So, I have obtained a fantastic grid containing the product list!
Now, there's a really bad check box that gets displayed for a Boolean value.
I'd rather have a Yes/No kind of thing. So I googled and found this fantastic article: http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/10/overriding-displayfor-and-editorfor-to-create-custom-outputs-for-mvc/ .
The problem is that the output he's showing is not conditional, so my code
looks like this:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<string>
@if @Model == True
{
  <span>Yes</span>
}
@else{
  <span> No </span>
}
```

But VS 2013 is all squiggly about it, which is usually a bad omen!
When I try to run it, I see the check box. Heh... lots to learn...
Anyway, I have noticed a similar question to mine, i.e. why the DisplayFor template was not showing. I looked at the OP's code and noticed he had put a DataType attribute that my property did not have (and that now has).
However, when I tried to use the DataType attribute in my model, VS got all squiggly again - bad omen!
When I tried to compile, geez, all hell broke loose and I got 6 compile errors (but that's progress at least, from simply ignoring everything!).
The errors are these:

```
Error   1   Expected a "{" but found a "@".  Block statements must be enclosed in "{" and "}".  You cannot use single-statement control-flow statements in CSHTML pages. For example, the following is not allowed:

@if(isLoggedIn)
    <p>Hello, @user</p>

Instead, wrap the contents of the block in "{}":

@if(isLoggedIn) {
    <p>Hello, @user</p>
}   c:\Users\Andrea\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ARSoftLabs.it\ARSoftLabs.it\Views\Products\DisplayTemplates\ProductHasTrial.cshtml    2   4   ARSoftLabs.it
Error   2   ) expected  c:\Users\Andrea\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ARSoftLabs.it\ARSoftLabs.it\Views\Products\DisplayTemplates\ProductHasTrial.cshtml    1   1   ARSoftLabs.it
Error   3   Syntax error, '(' expected  c:\Users\Andrea\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ARSoftLabs.it\ARSoftLabs.it\Views\Products\DisplayTemplates\ProductHasTrial.cshtml    2   4   ARSoftLabs.it
Error   4   Invalid expression term 'else'  c:\Users\Andrea\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ARSoftLabs.it\ARSoftLabs.it\Views\Products\DisplayTemplates\ProductHasTrial.cshtml    6   2   ARSoftLabs.it
Error   5   The type or namespace name 'DataTypeAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\Users\Andrea\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ARSoftLabs.it\ARSoftLabs.it\Models\Product.cs 20  10  ARSoftLabs.it
Error   6   The type or namespace name 'DataType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  c:\Users\Andrea\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ARSoftLabs.it\ARSoftLabs.it\Models\Product.cs 20  10  ARSoftLabs.it
```

So basically I think it's telling me I don't know jack about Razor, which is quite frankly true. Anyway, the System.ComponentModel is being used because the DisplayName attribute works like a charm and MSDN claims that DataType is in the same assembly.

Ideas? Pointers?

Thanks!

A

Comment: It would appear that DataType resides in an external package. I have tried to look in nuGet but can't seem to find it. Heh.

Comment: I finally realised that it is - yes - in ComponentModel, but one level deeper in DataAnnotations. I have managed to build it but now my new migration does not work! Geez.